Sobolev-Poincaré Inequality equivalence
In my studies I have encountered the so called Sobolev-Poincaré Inequalities. Bellow, $p$ and $q$ satisfy certain relation, $u$ is a member of certain space and $\Omega$ is a domain with certain properties:

$\parallel u \parallel_{L_p(\Omega)} \ \leq \ C \parallel \nabla u \parallel_{L_q(\Omega)} $

$\displaystyle \inf_{c\in \mathbb{R}}\parallel u -c \parallel_{L_p(\Omega)} \ \leq \ C \parallel \nabla u \parallel_{L_q(\Omega)}$


My question is rather simple: are these inequalitites equivalent? if so, why some texts prefer one formulation over the other?

They cant be equivalent (trivially) as the first inequality does not hold for constant functions, while the second does. Could you please be more specific about the function spaces?

That's a good observation. Let us assume that the space of fuctions is built in such a way that it prevents cases as the one you point out. Can we assert the equivalence? or is there something that makes the question non-sense?
